# Enabling only obfuscation but not code shrinking in Android?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, minify, android-proguard

I want to enable only the obfuscation feature in ProGuard but at the same time disable code shrinking, so I set

```
minifyEnabled false
useProguard true
```

However, now release compilation doesn't generate a `mapping.txt` any longer, which I guess indicates that no obfuscation is being done? I thought `minifyEnabled` controlled code shrinking and `useProguard` controlled obfuscation, but that doesn't seem to be the case?

What exactly does the `useProguard` flag do, and how do I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`minifyEnabled true`: it runs ProGuard

`shrinkResources true`: it removes resources that ProGuard flagged as unused.

While removing unwanted files from your DEX, your APK size also reduces. For your purpose, you can set this attribute to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `-dontshrink` option to keep all unused classes, methods and resources.

Read [Shrinking options](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#shrinkingoptions), where documentation says

> -dontshrink

Specifies not to shrink the input class files. By default, shrinking is applied; all classes and class members are removed, except for the ones listed by the various -keep options, and the ones on which they depend, directly or indirectly. A shrinking step is also applied after each optimization step, since some optimizations may open the possibility to remove more classes and class members.